# What's the difference between void and cv void?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I have come across **the type "cv void"** in the latest draft of the C++ standard (*N4606*) :

> #### 8.3.3 [dcl.mptr], paragraph 3
>
> A pointer to member shall not point to a static member of a class (9.2.3), a member with reference type, **or “cv void”**.

With a little bit of research, I found **"cv void" is a real type**, but I have no idea what's the difference **compared to the type void**. Can you explain it **with an example** (maybe with a code) ?

---

**EDIT** :

- I sort of expected cv would stand for cv-qualified. My question here is, why do we need to "cv-qualify" the type void?
- The reason I said **"cv void is a real type"** is that, the standard actually defined it:

  > #### 3.9.1 [basic.fundamental], paragraph 9
  >
  > A type cv void is an incomplete type that cannot be completed; such a type has an empty set of values...

Comment: `const volatile void`.

Comment: Rather, specifically, a `void` with a `const` or `volatile` qualifier.

Comment: What's the point of cv-qualified void?

Comment: There isn't one, hence the passage saying you can't have one here.

Comment: @Il-seobBae it's there just to support `const void* p = &something;`. E.g. `void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb `const void *p = &something;` is acceptable, but `const void X:: *p = &something;` is not (according to this passage) ?

Comment: @Il-seobBae that is not susprising at all. There is no "void escape" for member pointers. With member pointers, you have to know the exact type of the member. C does not have member pointers, so the argument that we need backward compatibility with C does not apply here.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Do you mean to say that, **if it wasn't for C**, `const void *p = &something;` would **also** end up having an error?

Comment: @Il-seobBae no. but the burden of not having the feature would be much lower.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Can I ask you one more question? Why does the above paragraph only talk about cv void? I mean, a pointer to a void member (without cv) should also be prohibited (actually, g++ told me it's an error).

Comment: @Il-seobBae i recommend to make a stackoverflow question for this, rather than putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"cv void" is not a real type. "cv" here is a shorthand for "possibly cv-qualified", which means "may have a `const` or a `volatile` on it".

The passage means that a pointer-to-member may not point to an object of the following types: `void`, `const void`, `volatile void` and `const volatile void`. It's fairly obvious, since such objects cannot exist in the first place, but I guess it's nice to be clear.

Comment: At this point, what I don't understand is that, why the above paragraph only talks about "cv void". It sounds as if "void" (without cv) was acceptable. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Il-seobBae: Granted, the wording is pants. Without opening up my copy of the standard, I actually couldn't tell you if it means any `void` or specifically those with a non-empty _cv-qualifier_.

Comment: ["In this International Standard, the notation cv (or cv1 , cv2 , etc.), used in the description of types, represents an arbitrary set of cv-qualifiers, i.e., one of {const}, {volatile}, {const, volatile}, **or the empty set**."](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.type.qualifier#5)

Comment: ^ There you go then. So it means "void in any of its forms".

Answer (score 4):

We don't "need" to allow `void` to be cv-qualified. However, it's simpler to allow it than it is to make a special exception forbidding it.

But it does actually have an important practical use: allowing `void` to be cv-qualified allows us to write cv-correct code with pointers-to-`void`.

Answer (score 3):

"cv `void`" means `void` which is optionally `const`- or `volatile`-qualified. Simply `void` is not so qualified.

And for some reason, someone obviously thought it was a good idea to forbid that for member-pointers (in contrast to normal pointers).
Seems someone is no fan of untyped memory...

Answer (score 3):

> why do we need to "`cv`-qualify" the type `void`?

Same reason you would need to *cv*-qualify any other type. For instance, [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)'s signature is:

```
void* memcpy( void* dest, const void* src, std::size_t count );
```

The `src` argument is a pointer to `const void`, because the memory pointed to by `src` will not be modified by the function. This let's me pass in a pointer to a `const` object:

```
const POD pod{...};
POD new_pod;
memcpy(&new_pod, &pod, sizeof(pod));
```